# JQuery get element id data from ajax loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm loading data from a PHP page with JQuery and it works fine. Now I want that when I click on one of these loaded elements an alert shows the id of the selected element. How can I do? Because I want to send the if later on using ajax. I tried this code, but it didn't work.

HTML

```
 <li><a href="#"><strong>CATEGORY</strong><span> MENU ELEMENTS</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a id="id_1" data-target='post_category'>Sub_1</a></li>
            <li><a id="id_2" data-target='post_category'>Sub_2</a></li>
            <li><a id="id_3" data-target='post_category'>Sub_3</a></li>
            <li><a id="id_4" data-target='post_category'>Sub_4</a></li>
            <li><a id="id_5" data-target='post_category'>Sub_5</a></li>
            <li><a id="id_6" data-target='post_category'>Sub_6</a></li>
            <li><a id="id_7" data-target='post_category'>Sub_7</a></li>
         <ul>
  </li>
```

JQuery

```
<script>

    $(document).on("click", "a", function() {
        alert('worked!');
    });

</script>
```

sending data code

```
$(document).on("click","a",function(e){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: "id=" + $(this).attr("id"),
url: "post_category.php"
});
});
```

as I wrote that the alert didn't appear which mean click event in JQuery code doesn't work for some reason.

---

Thank you for your tips I tried them all, but the found the cause of the problem it's from the script  that loading the page using ajax.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //set trigger and container
            var trigger = $('#nav ul li a'),
                container = $('#container');
            //do on click
            trigger.on('click', function(e){
                /***********/
                 e.preventDefault();

                //get the link location that was clicked
                pageurl = $(this).attr('href');



                //to change the browser URL to th  if(pageurl!=window.location){
                  window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl+'.php');



               /* reload content without refresh */
                //set loading img
                $('#container').append('<div id = "loading">WAIT...  <img src = "img/ajax-loader-small.gif" alt="Currently loading"   /></div>');
                //change img location to center
                $("#loading").css({"position": "absolute", "left": "50%", "top": "50%"});
                //get the  trigger to reload the contents
                var $this = $(this),
                    target = $this.data('target');

                container.load(target + '.php');


                return false;

            });
        });
        // fix url in the browser when click on backward and foreword  arrows
        $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
            $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
                $('#container').html(data);
            }});
        });



    </script>
```

I really don't know which part that cause this problem. Please help/

Comment: Have you loaded jquery? Any errors in your console/firebug/devtools?

Comment: have you checked "Prevent this page for creating additional dialogs" ? Use console.log instead of alert.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question please review it. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Live() is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is return false in the loading receipt.

I removed return false and kept    `e.preventDefault();`   so it will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the probelm is with your identification of which element is clicked. I would do it this way: First, in your html move the `id` to the `li` element

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><strong>CATEGORY</strong> MENU ELEMENTS</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li id="id_1"><a data-target="post_category"></a>Sub_1</li>
  <li id="id_2"><a data-target="post_category"></a>Sub_2</li>
  <li id="id_3"><a data-target="post_category"></a>Sub_3</li>
  <li id="id_4"><a data-target="post_category"></a>Sub_4</li>
  <li id="id_5"><a  data-target="post_category"></a>Sub_5</li>
  <li id="id_6"><a data-target="post_category"></a>Sub_6</li>
  <li id="id_7"><a data-target="post_category"></a>Sub_7</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

You should then be able to get the id with:

```
jQuery("#container-fluid > section > div > div.box-body > ul > li > ul").children().on("click", function() {
    alert('worked!');
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question please review it. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Two things: what makes you say the problem is 'from the script that loading the page using ajax'? Can you show us any error message? It would help. Second, I'd need to see what's in your ajax url location.pathname file that's generating the data returned.

Comment: I fixed this problem  it was because of the 'return false' in the loading page ajax script.  I inserted the code in the question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It's working fine.

```
    <li><a href="#"><strong>CATEGORY</strong><span> MENU ELEMENTS</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a id="id_1" class="abc" data-id="id_1" data-target='post_category'>Sub_1</a></li>
        <li><a id="id_2" class="abc" data-id="id_2" data-target='post_category'>Sub_2</a></li>
        <li><a id="id_3" class="abc" data-id="id_3" data-target='post_category'>Sub_3</a></li>
        <li><a id="id_4" class="abc" data-id="id_4" data-target='post_category'>Sub_4</a></li>
        <li><a id="id_5" class="abc" data-id="id_5" data-target='post_category'>Sub_5</a></li>
        <li><a id="id_6" class="abc" data-id="id_6" data-target='post_category'>Sub_6</a></li>
        <li><a id="id_7" class="abc" data-id="id_7" data-target='post_category'>Sub_7</a></li>
        <ul>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".abc").click(function () {
        var id_value = $(this).data('id');
        alert(id_value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question please review it. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are setting up click events before the links are added to the dom. Ajax calls are a little bit different than the regular functions. They don't block your code so when you do an ajax call, javascript calls the function and doesn't wait for the response. It goes and implements the rest of the functions.

Simpler version of your function

```
 $.get(url, function (data) {
        // success -> Usually just calling your function here solves the problem. 
    }).done(function () { 
        setupClickListener(); // If it doesn't append this to it for extra security.
    });

function setupClickListener(){
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
        alert('worked!');
    });
}
```

Comment: no I setting them after the links for sure.  Thank you, I updated the question please review it. I really appreciate your help.